# How can i fill a multidimensional array from a text file?

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, multidimensional-array

EDIT:

The original values are these:

```
        mArray[0, 0] = 0;
        mArray[0, 1] = 1;
        mArray[0, 2] = 2;
        mArray[0, 3] = 3;
        mArray[1, 0] = 0;
        mArray[1, 1] = 1;
        mArray[1, 2] = 2;
        mArray[1, 3] = 3;
        mArray[2, 0] = 0;
        mArray[2, 1] = 2;
        mArray[2, 2] = 2;
        mArray[2, 3] = 3;
        mArray[3, 0] = 0;
        mArray[3, 1] = 1;
        mArray[3, 2] = 3;
        mArray[3, 3] = 3;
```

Then I store all the values in a text file, that is why I have all my values like this inside the text file ...

```
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
0
2
2
3
0
1
3
3
```

My real problem is to how to refill the same array from the text file?

```
int mArray[,];
```

How can I do that in order to fill my array from the data stored in the text file? As always, using C# and in this case, WPF.

Comment: So is it a two dimensional array in which the second dimension has a size of one, because you only have one dimensional data.

Comment: Why is this multidimentional? I only see one dimension.

Comment: Are you trying to "unflatten" these lines of text (turn them from one-dimensional into two-dimensional)? If so, it's not entirely clear from your example how that is intended to be done... what is the expectation here?

Comment: I have edited the post with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you maybe mean something like this?
this function populate a bidimensional array as best as it can. if you have a 5x5 array and 7 lines the function return a 5*5 array which have the first 7 cell ({0,0}, {0,1}, {0,2}, {0,3}, {0,4}, {1,0}, {1,1}) setted to whatever there is in your text file. the remaining cell are null.

```
    public static string[,] GetData(int row, int column, string filePath)
    {
        int[,] data = new string[row, column];
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filePath))
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < data.GetLength(0); r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < data.GetLength(1); c++)
                {
                    if (reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        return data;
                    }

                    //Note that Parse throw error if the string is not a valid int
                    //use it only if you anticipate that your file contain int only and other
                    //string should be considered as errors. otherwise use TryParse
                    data[r, c] = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Comment: This actually worked, I had to modify it a little bit, but it worked!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure of your question.
Are you simply trying to fill an array with lines of a file?
That is simple and this will do it:

```
int[] mArray = File.ReadAllLines("pathAndFilename").Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Is that sufficient?
If not, then please clarify your question a little.

Using more info I think you want something more like this:

```
        private static int[,] FillArrays(string file, int rightLength)
        {
            int[] mArray = File.ReadAllLines(file).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
            int size = mArray.Length / rightLength;
            if (((mArray.Length ^ rightLength) >= 0) && (mArray.Length % rightLength != 0))
            {
                size++;
            }
            int[,] arrayDos = new int[size, rightLength];
            int counter = 0;
            int arrayNum = 0;
            foreach (int i in mArray)
            {
                arrayDos[arrayNum, counter] = i;
                counter++;
                if (counter == rightLength)
                {
                    counter = 0;
                    arrayNum++;
                }
            }
            return arrayDos;
        }
```

And call it like this:

```
int[,] mArray = FillArrays(@"Z:\testnums.txt", 4);
```

You can pass in the right side size:

```
{int[8, 2]}
    [0, 0]: 0
    [0, 1]: 1
    [0, 2]: 2
    [0, 3]: 3
    [1, 0]: 0
    [1, 1]: 1
    [1, 2]: 2
    [1, 3]: 3
    [2, 0]: 0
    [2, 1]: 2
    [2, 2]: 2
    [2, 3]: 3
    [3, 0]: 0
    [3, 1]: 1
    [3, 2]: 3
    [3, 3]: 3
```

2 will also work with your example data.

```
{int[8, 2]}
    [0, 0]: 0
    [0, 1]: 1
    [1, 0]: 2
    [1, 1]: 3
    [2, 0]: 0
    [2, 1]: 1
    [3, 0]: 2
    [3, 1]: 3
    [4, 0]: 0
    [4, 1]: 2
    [5, 0]: 2
    [5, 1]: 3
    [6, 0]: 0
    [6, 1]: 1
    [7, 0]: 3
    [7, 1]: 3
```

Comment: and It has to be a int[,] mArray; , not a int[] mArray;

Comment: You want it to populate into a multidimensional array?
Based on your added text above is it simply 4 elements in the second array, or what exactly?

Comment: No problem.
Glad to help